# Pobability of getting a particular number as the largest with replacement

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Fifteen coupons are numbered 1 to 15. Seven coupons are selected at random one at a time with replacement then What is the probability that the largest number appearing on the selected coupon is 9?

My approach:-

I understood that it will be $9^7-8^7$ (excluding cases with 8 as maximum)
But i was also thinking this way

first i fill 1 place out of 7 by 9 and then fill remaining 6 places with any digit from 1 to 9. So total favourable cases = 7C1 * $9^6$.

But these are not equal numerically. What is wrong in 2nd way. Pls clarify.

Comment: Since you are allowing replacement you are badly overcounting.  Specifically, any choice that contains $n$ $9's$ is counted $n$ times.

Comment: sir i did not understand. Kindly elaborate. It is like 1 nine already present. Then 1-9 present in remaining cases. It ensures atleast 1 nine right. How is it overcounting i am not able to vizualise... In textbook the answer is given as $9^7-8^7$ which i could make out from this. But i did not understand where i went wrong

Comment: Consider the selection $9,1,9,9, 2, 7,9$ as an example.   You count that once when you choose to put a $9$ in the first slot, and then choose the other six at random.  Then you count it again when you choose to put a $9$ in the third slot.  And again for the fourth slot, and again for the seventh.  So so count this particular choice four times.

Comment: If that is still unclear, then I suggest writing it out completely for a smaller sample space.  Suppose you are rolling two dice and that you ask for the probability that the greatest roll is a $4$.  The first method gives $4^2-3^2=7$.  The second gives $2\times 4=8$.  Once again, the second method is over counting.  Specifically, it counts the pair $(4,4)$ twice.

Comment: Oh yes! understood now. Thank you sir :)

Comment: @NascimentodeCos your example would work if you sampled without replacement: then you would have only one '9', and then all allocations would be unique, i.e. you wouldn't be able to get,for example, $9,9,\ldots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to worry about overcounting here. Using lulu's example with 2 dice, the probability to get two '4' is $\frac{1}{36}$, not $\frac{2}{36}$, because in case two '4' are different (e.g. two dice are read and blue and the order matters), the total number of outcomes would be $2 \times 36 = 72$ (because for each choice, e.g. 1 and 6, you get 2 sequences: 1R6B, 1B6R).

Another example: you have a two-sided dice with numbers 1 and 0, and you toss them $n$ times. If the outcomes with the same number of 0s and 1s is the same, you have a total of $n+1$ outcomes (all 0s, all 1s, n-1 0s + one 1, etc). But the probability of getting, for example, all 0s would not be $\frac{1}{n+1}$, it would still be $\frac{1}{2^n}$.

Applying this logic to your case, the probability to get the sequence with the largest number=9 (imagine you have a 15-sided dice that you toss 7 times) is 
$$
1 - \frac{6^7}{15^7}
$$